# Prove $\sinh1\Bigl(1+2{\sum}_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n\pi)^2+1}\Bigr)=1$ for $-1\lt x \lt 1$

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, summation-method

This is a follow up topic from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443124/given-a-fourier-series-fx-whats-the-difference-between-the-value-the-expan) previous post.

The Fourier series for $f(x)=e^x$ is $$f(x)=e^x=\sinh1\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n\pi)^2+1}\left(\cos(n\pi x)-n\pi\sin(n\pi x)\right)\right)$$

The value of the Fourier series $f(x)=e^x$ at $x=2$ and $x=1$ are the same:
$$f(2)=\sinh1\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n\pi)^2+1}\right)$$

$$f(0)=e^0=\sinh1\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n\pi)^2+1}\right)$$

Could someone please prove that 
$$\sinh1\Bigl(1+2{\sum}_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n\pi)^2+1}\Bigr)=1?$$ The interval is $-1\lt x \lt 1$

Thank you.

Comment: [Again](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443124/given-a-fourier-series-fx-whats-the-difference-between-the-value-the-expan)???

Comment: But... This is what Dominik answers in your other question.

Comment: He gives the theorem. You just have to put in $x=0$, where the function is continuous, and $e^0=1$.

Comment: I was not the down voter, so I'm not alone...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334550/evaluate-the-series-in-closed-form/334560#334560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is, on purpose, a word-by-word copy of the answer by @Dominik (to show OP that this is essentially the same question as discussed in the comments), with the small necessary changes of course. I hope Dominik does not care.

Define the function $f$ to be $\exp(x)$ on $[-1, 1)$ and continue it periodically. Then by the Dirichlet condition the Fourier series of $f$ converges for all $x$ to $\frac{1}{2}(f(x+) + f(x-))$. Since the function is continuous at $x = 0$, the Fourier series at this point will converge to $e^0=1$.

Hence,
$$
\sinh1\Bigl(1+2{\sum}_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n\pi)^2+1}\Bigr)=1.
$$

**Edit**
Upon request. $f(x+)$ denotes the right limit $\lim_{t\to x+}f(t)$ and $f(x-)$ denotes the left limit $\lim_{t\to x-}f(t)$. In the case $f$ is continuous at $x$, one has $f(x+)=f(x-)=f(x)$.

Comment: Great, now I need you to do one more thing show in that answer the substitution of the values into $\frac{1}{2}(f(x+) + f(x-))$. This is what I asked of Dominik but no such luck. The reason I ask is because I don't know what $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ actually mean. If you do this I will consider this question concluded.

Comment: Did you read the link Dominik gave: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions? The definitions are in there.

Comment: @mrf Yes I did it was in Dominiks post

Comment: You could have mentioned in your question that the notations $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ were the problem. Nevertheless, not it is updated with that information included.

Comment: @mickep Thanks, that was all I wanted to see.